# How to serve NodeJS form app using zeit now server

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer, vercel

I am running a simple nodejs form processing app on zeit now server and deploying using now CLI scripts.
This Node app although working well on the localhost within the said port number (like this: http://localhost:8081/myaction), however the same function is not workinig for me on the zeit server wherein I replace the localhost with the server URL given by NOW build script.

Here is my now.json and I am also providing access to the git repository which has the node server app thaat processes the form, sends an E-mail and serves a Thank You page in the last step.

Node Server App repo: https://github.com/jnsrikanth/node-form-server2

now.json file contents:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [{ "src": "index.js", "use": "@now/node-server" }],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/public/thank-you/dist/",
      "dest": "/index.html",
      "methods": ["GET"]
    },
    {
      "src": "/",
      "dest": "/index.js",
      "methods": ["POST"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The package.json and the remaining code can be found in the repository. It would be great if I can find some pointers here.

Also please note that in my form I am calling action="https://zeit-url:8081/myaction" method="POST" where  8081 is the port on which the express app is listening for processing the POST method with form data.

Answer (score 0):

In your *now.json* replace `/` with `/myaction`

```
...
{
   "src": "/myaction",
   "dest": "/index.js",
   "methods": ["POST"]
}
...
```

And just call https://zeit-url/myaction (without port number)
I hope it will help you

Comment: I tried it, I am still getting a 404 not found where I see that now it is trying to redirect to the page index.html at https://zeit-url/index.html where I believe it is not finding. The actual location of the index.html (form thank you page) is at /public/thank-you/dist

I also did not see the email come through to my emai id (nodemailer operation)

Do I also need to add a GET iinside now.json with the /public/thank-you/dist folder? and the file index.html?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but i kept the GET method as it is in the now.json file...the result is the same as what i reported above in the comment, getting a 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to convert that `now.json` into a `vercel.json` and, based on the github repo you provided, update it so looks like:

```json
"version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/public/thank-you/dist/",
      "dest": "/public/index.html",
      "methods": ["GET"]
    },
    {
      "src": "/",
      "dest": "/index.js",
      "methods": ["POST"]
    }
  ]
```

- You need to verify this server runs without problems on local machine.
- Since you are using the `builds` `vercel.json` option, you need to ensure all the dependencies, as `node_modules` etc are uploaded to vercel, either by deploying file from the `vercel-cli`, or using some pipeline or CI action.